# Sending tab screenshots to a remote server from a firefox addon

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I have firefox addon (made using the firefox addon sdk) which when instructed takes a screenshot of the currently active tab and sends it in an ajax request to a remote server.

The following code in addon-script main.js is responsible for taking getting the thumbnail

```
var tab_image_data=tabs.activeTab.getThumbnail();
var tab_image_data = base64.encode(tab_image_data);
panel.port.emit("screenshot",{image_data:tab_image_data});
```

The image data generated by the function getThumbnail() is sent to a content script file belonging to a panel.

In the content script the following code is responsible for sending the image data to the server

```
var tab_image_data=addonmessage.image_data;
var myBlob = new Blob([tab_image_data], { "type" : "text/base64data"} );
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('img',myBlob);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://xyz.abc.com/imageshot/index.php", true);
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log('all done: sq');
    } else {
        console.log('Nope');
    }
};
xhr.send(formData);
```

Everything works fine and the image file is created on server in jpeg format. But when I try to view that image, the windows photo viewer gives a not supported file format error.

I tried to base64 encode the data before sending it but that did not work as well. Suprisingly I have a chrome extension that performs a similar function and that works flawlessly. In both cases the same php script is being used on the server side.

Any help regarding this matter will be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have the PHP code posted here, that might be part of the problem as well - the data JS is sending might need to be processed / changed in PHP before being put in the file. For example - what does the file on the server look like if you open it in a text editor? Is it the Base64 text?